# How can i check the Bluetooth is ON or OFF in IOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using GameKit.framework for implementing Bluetooth in my app, but in didLoad I want to check if Bluetooth is turned on or turned off. Could anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking Bluetooth Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494664/checking-bluetooth-status)

Answer (score 2):

There's a *private framework* called `BluetoothManager` which can get the status easily. However, if you use it, your app will **probably be rejected from the app store**. So, only use this for apps you intend to distribute some other way.

Include [this header](https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/blob/master/BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h) in your project. Then you may write:

```
#import "BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h"

BluetoothManager *bt;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    bt = [[BluetoothManager alloc] init];
}

- (BOOL)getBluetoothEnabled {
    return [bt enabled];
}
```

Then, you just call `getBluetoothEnabled`.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer. "It's impossible" is rarely true (how people think jailbreak tweaks and apps do stuff?)...

Comment: What irritates me is that this framework has been around long enough for Apple to at least expose *part* of this functionality. For them not to expose something as simple as "is Bluetooth enabled?" is shameful in my books. (Probably why I quit doing iOS development).

Comment: Exactly. Agreed. (I'm wondering what I will do once iOS N is released and can't be jailbroken... Will I switch to Android or what? But c'mon, it's crap!)

Comment: it is giving me error Lexical or Preprocessor Issue and 'BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h' file not found

Comment: Well...you need to take the header I linked and put it in a `BluetoothManager/` subfolder...

Comment: can you please test it create project and add these files in your project and then #import "BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h" after that it will show the error

Comment: I tested it. It works, though you do need to make sure to link in the `BluetoothManager` private framework from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs/<SDKversion>/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24609/discussion-between-jaspreet-singh-and-nneonneo)

Answer (score 0):

You can't check with the current SDK. There is no **Public API** available for this.

Comment: Well, no *public* API. `BluetoothManager` has been able to do this for a while.

Comment: @nneonneo How it will be possible by BluetoothManage can you explain me and provide me code or link

Comment: As it is a private framework, you won't be able to submit to the app store. If you're OK with that, I will post the answer.

Comment: There is a way on iOS 5 and above using CoreBluetooth. The class you can use is CBCentralManager. It has a property 'state' that you can check to see if Bluetooth is on or not. (the enum CBCentralManagerState has the value(s) you want to check against).

Comment: @PushpakNarasimhan: This has the disadvantage of popping up a dialog box if Bluetooth is not enabled. You cannot suppress the dialog AFAIK.