# Detecting when Bluetooth is disabled on iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth, audiosession

I'm developing blog speaker app.

I wanna pause the audio when bluetooth is disabled like iPod app.  I thought it's not possible without using private api after reading this.
[Check if Bluetooth is Enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657502/check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled)

But, my customer told me that Rhapsody and DI Radio apps both support it.

Then I found iOS5 has Core Bluetooth framework.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf

CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff status seems like the one.

But, the description says this api only supports Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices.
Did anyone try doing the same thing?

I want to support current popular bluetooth headsets, or bluetooth enabled steering wheel on the car.  I don't know if it's worth trying when it only supports some brand new bluetooth.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is here.  Checking CBCentralManagerState will allow you to see if the Bluetooth for the device is turned on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For audio, focusing on Bluetooth specifically sounds like the wrong approach.

I think what you're looking for is [Handling Audio Hardware Route Changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingRouteChanges/HandlingRouteChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH12-SW1).

You'll notice that all of the following cause the the built-in iPod app to pause:

- Bluetooth device is removed (possibly because bluetooth has been disabled).
- Headphones are unplugged.
- Device is removed from docking station.

You get all that correct behavior when you use the Audio Session API.

Comment: It seems like this is what I wanted.  If I can support all the behaviors at one time, that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On BLE you will get an update on the manager containing the state:

```
 enum {
CBCentralManagerStateUnknown = 0, // State unknown,
update imminent.
CBCentralManagerStateResetting, // The connection with the system service was      momentarily lost,
update imminent.
CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported, // The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.
CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized, // The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.
CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff, // Bluetooth is currently powered off.
CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn, // Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.
};
```

which you can check on the mandatory callback with e.g

```
centralManager:didUpdateState...{
if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff)
{
[musicPlayer pause]
}
}
```