# iOS CoreBluetooth passively check if Bluetooth is enabled without prompting user to turn Bluetooth on

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The scenario is as follows.  I have an already deployed app being used by people.  I am *considering* implementing some experimental Bluetooth Low Energy features, but before I do, I want to conduct an "in the wild" survey of the number of users who already have Bluetooth turned on/leave Bluetooth on all the time.  So, I would just like to check this in the background and send back to a server statistics on number of users with Bluetooth already on, without ever actually using Bluetooth communications.

I have successfully instantiated a `CBCentralManager` in my app and can retrieve the Bluetooth status both immediately after instantiation and when the Bluetooth state updates via [`centralManagerDidUpdateState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManagerDidUpdateState%3a).  So that is all good.  The problem I am having is that if the state is `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff`, then the device brings up an alert prompting the user to "Turn On Bluetooth to Allow [app name] to Connect to Accessories".  It is this prompt I am trying to avoid.  At this stage I just wish to survey the number of users who leave Bluetooth On - I don't wish to use the Bluetooth connection.

So, *is there a way to check the Bluetooth status without prompting the user if you don't intend on using the Bluetooth connection?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iOS 7 has a new `options` parameter in the create of `CBCentralManager` to turn this off, named CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey

I'd love a solution for earlier iOS.

Comment: Nice find.  Are you referring to `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey`?  If you decide to expand your answer to specify which call this is passed to/link to further info I'll mark this the accepted answer.  Otherwise I'll do an edit on this answer when I get a chance to look at it again in more detail.

Comment: Yes, use CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey, try     myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}];

Comment: Possible **SWIFT 5** answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72205073/4543645

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following when you initialise the `CBCentralManager`.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO};
self.manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
```

I may have not explained it correctly, please right into the comment if there's any concern.

Comment: @Maximilian are you sure? It works on my iOS 8.4.1 iPad Mini 2.

Comment: @po5i 
`var options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false]
self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)`

Comment: in iOS13 this now prompts users permission to access bluetooth.

Comment: Possible **SWIFT 5** answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72205073/4543645