# CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey AlertView / Alert Controller OK Button

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uialertview, uialertcontroller, cbcentralmanager

In the app, I am creating a video player with a 'remote control' with two different iOS devices using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), where one device is the video player and the other is sending messages to play, pause, rewind, etc. Here I have the central manager being created with the CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey, nil];
        centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
```

An alert view / alert controller similar to this one will pop up if the device does not have its Bluetooth setting turned on (The one I get has bold font).

[CLBeaconRegion, how to turn off warning: Turn On Bluetooth to Allow * to Connect to Accessories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484304/clbeaconregion-how-to-turn-off-warning-turn-on-bluetooth-to-allow-to-connect)

I want to add more functionality to the OK button when it is pressed other than resignFirstResponder.

What am I missing that I need to modify what the OK button does in this alert view / alert controller?
Methods I have break pointed and logged but still failing to catch:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Button Index =%ld",(long)buttonIndex);
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)buttonIndex);
}

-(void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSLog(@"alert view cancel");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need change options of centralManager, form [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; to [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
2. implement CBCentralManagerDeletgate with centralManagerDidUpdateState: method.
3. In centralManagerDidUpdateState: method you will create alertview

   - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
     {
     if (_bluetoothManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff)
     {
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                         message:@"my alert"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil ] show];
     }
     }
4. In alertView:clikedButtonAtIndex: you will overide with your code

   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
       NSLog(@"%ld", (long)buttonIndex);
   }

Comment: Is there a way to set a value of CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey in the Info.plist file?