# iOS CBCentralManager "Turn on Bluetooth" prompt and CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey default value

Tags: ios, cocoa, bluetooth

[iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Central_Manager_Initialization_Options) says that `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` default value is `NO`.

I'm not specyfing ANY options while instantiating `CBCentralManager`

```
[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

but it still shows the "Turn On Bluetooth to Allow..." prompt.

Is it a bug in documentation, or am I doing something wrong ?

**Edit:**

I've found this:

http://chris.cm/determine-whether-bluetooth-is-enabled-on-ios-passively/

And this:

[iOS CoreBluetooth passively check if Bluetooth is enabled without prompting user to turn Bluetooth on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412866/ios-corebluetooth-passively-check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-without-prompting-user)

which seem to suggest that you have to explicitly set the `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` to `NO`, which suggests that there is a bug in documentation ? **I'm just looking for someone to confirm.**

**Edit 2:**

after setting `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` to `0` the problem seems to be resolved. **but I'm still looking for some explanation, because it seems highly illogical that the documentation says one thing and program another.**

Comment: Have you specified Bluetooth background mode?

Comment: No, I'm just using bluetooth to find out if BLE is on, or off.

Comment: Do you use any external frameworks(libraries) which work with bluethooth?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, I have this particular inconsistency in my code right now.

The docs says that NO it should be the default value but that isn't the case, you have to force it, the default behaviour is YES.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation as well, in the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW2), creating a manager, there is this paragraph:

> When you create a central manager, the central manager calls the
>   centralManagerDidUpdateState: method of its delegate object. You must
>   implement this delegate method to ensure that Bluetooth low energy is
>   supported and available to use on the central device. For more
>   information about how to implement this delegate method, see
>   CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference.

I wonder if the prompt is part of that delegate call, if the state is "PoweredOff"

Logically it makes some sense, if you are launching and trying to communicate via bluetooth, this is something the user is expecting. They may not have bluetooth on, this covers that use case without forcing the user to go to the settings app, before they can use your app.

Comment: "I wonder if the prompt is part of that delegate call, if the state is "PoweredOff" -- It's not, because the prompt happens a lot later, when the app is suspended and the user is using other apps (for example).

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: A couple of devices that are all >8.0