# iOS BlE harassment reminder

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I developed an App used CoreBlueTooth and support background task. but even when I use other Apps,the reminder(Turn On BlueTooth to Allow "xxxxx" to Connect to Accessories) of BLE may appear.
such as:[image]
Anyone can tell me how to resolve?

Comment: Turn Bluetooth on before you run the app. This alert is nothing to do with background mode. It is simply informing the user that the app wants to use Bluetooth but Bluetooth is currently off

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412866/ios-corebluetooth-passively-check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-without-prompting-user

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The users always not operate like this.
They only turn on the Bluetooth when they needed, and when they use other Apps such as Facebook, the alert may appear. That's the trouble.

Comment: Did you see the linked answer?  Try setting the power alert option to NO, even though the documentation says that this is the default value

Comment: Yes. Got it.I think that's the solution I found for a long time. Thanks very very much.