# Check if bluetooth is on without system popup on iOS 7

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios7

In iOS 6 [it's not possible to check if bluetooth is on without a system popup being shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533269/ios-check-if-bluetooth-is-on-without-system-alert-popup-to-user):

> CBCentralManager* testBluetooth = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil queue: nil];
>
> But, when [[CBCentralManager alloc] init...] happens, system popups an alert to user, if bluetooth is off.

Is this now possible in iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7, the prompt to enable bluetooth can be disabled if you initialize the manager with the following options.

```
myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}];
```

Comment: You can use `@NO` instead of `[ NSNumber numberWithBool:NO ]`