# Any way to turn on bluetooth programmatically on iOS7+

Tags: ios

I hear that iOS7 introduced this functionality with CBCentralManager but can't find how. Is possible? There is another way widthout use GKPeerPickerController?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, if the user has turned off Bluetooth all you can do is display an alert or message asking them to turn it on.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error" message: @"Please turn on Bluetooth in Settings" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
       [alert show]; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just check the status of CBCentralManager `state` https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCentralManagerState for 'powered off' and display an alert

Comment: I have already gone through it but i could not understand can u provide me sample code

Comment: Thank you Paulw11. +1 for u. The answer is correct.

Comment: Is there any any code to open iphone setting from the alert button

Comment: Not since the unofficial URL scheme was removed in iOS 5

Comment: But in apps like whats app we can move to settings using alert view button even in ios7.0.6

Comment: Only system dialogs can open settings (in iOS 8 you will be able to open *your apps* settings).  If I start my app that uses Bluetooth with Bluetooth turned off it displays a system alert that allows me to go to settings - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533269/ios-check-if-bluetooth-is-on-without-system-alert-popup-to-user

Answer (score 27):

You can also set the `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` key while instantiating the `CBCentralManager` to `true`. Then iOS will show the alert that "**Turn On Bluetooth to Allow "Your App" to connect to Accessories**". This alert will take you directly to the Bluetooth Setting page.

SampleCode In swift:

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
```

SampleCode In Objective-C:

```
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]
                                      initWithDelegate:self 
                                      queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() 
                                      options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @(YES)}];
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` is **true by default**. [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanageroptionshowpoweralertkey)

Answer (score -3):

use bluetooth Manager framework,

import the bluetoothManager Framework, create a object of bluetooth manager framework, as btManager,

write the following code in Bluetooth On button target

```
[btManager setPowered:YES];
[btManager setEnabled:YES];
```

all the best...

Comment: This is a private API which will get your app rejected on the App Store.

Comment: how we use this in swift?