# IOS How to enable bluetooth in swift code

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

On Android. The code that turns Bluetooth on and off.
I am trying to develop an iPhone, is there any function in swift code?

Comment: Please search before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838229/5316422

Comment: I am looking for code to control Bluetooth. I already know how to show alert

Comment: That post clearly states that its not possible. Best possible alternative is to show an alert which will take you to bluetooth setting inside device settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no public API can control Bluetooth on/off. [The post provided by Skywalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36890947/419348) said the same thing too, that post provides a private API to control the on/off status.

My project needs this function before, and I remember no public API to control Bluetooth on/off. But there are APIs to detect the status of bluetooth about on/off.

Comment: I dont think Apple will provide any API that can be used to control this. It will go against everything they preach