# Timestamp when the bluetooth turned ON/OFF

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-3gs

I am developing a application in which I need the timestamp when the bluetooth was on or off.

I googled almost all the way but didn't get any APIs regarding this. I tried the GameKit framework too but it also didn't work.

If anybody has any idea about it please let me know. Just a link or API related to this would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck? Please share if you have worked it out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955007/how-to-get-the-status-of-bluetooth-on-off-in-iphone-programatically