# How to check if bluetooth is enabled on iOS?

Tags: ios, qt

Is there any api in Qt that enables us to check whether bluetooth is turned on? I'm asking specifically for such support under iOS.

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE - an environment where you can edit code (any code, not just Qt code). It has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the status of bluetooth (ON/OFF) in iphone programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955007/how-to-get-the-status-of-bluetooth-on-off-in-iphone-programatically)