# CBPeripheralManager is unsupported in one app and powered on in other

Tags: ios, bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I've faced issue with `CBPeripheralManager` I have two apps first one is demo app where I've tested checking state of bluetooth and second is app that will have this working solutions.

According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31449624/989631) I've succesfuly implemented checking in demo app, but problem starts in second app. `CBPeripheralManager` always return state `Unsupported`. I'm testing it on iPhone 6s. I have now clue what I did wrong.

EDITED

**ViewController**

```
@property (nonatomic) BeaconManager *beaconManager;

@implementation StartViewController
...
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self setupBeaconManager];
    });
}
..

- (void) setupBeaconManager {
    NSString* pathForBeaconsInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BeaconsInfo" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary* beaconInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathForBeaconsInfo];
    NSString* uuidString = beaconInfo[@"UUID"];
    NSString* identifier = beaconInfo[@"identifier"];
    NSUUID* regionUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
    CLBeaconRegion* region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:regionUUID identifier:identifier];
    self.beaconManager = [[BeaconManager alloc]init];
    [self.beaconManager setBeaconDelegate:self];
    [self.beaconManager startMonitoring:region];
}

...

-(void) beaconManager:(BeaconManager *)manager bluetoothConnectionStatus:(CBPeripheralManagerState)status{
    NSString* msg = @"";
    switch (status) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            msg = @"on";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            msg = @"off";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting:
            msg = @"restarting";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            msg = @"unauthorized";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown:
            msg = @"unknown";
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported:
            msg = @"unsupported";
    }
    NSLog(@"Bluetooth Beacon %@",msg);
}
@end
```

**BeaconManager**

```
class BeaconManager: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    /**
    Method which check AuthorizationStatus for application, and will start monitoring if status is equal .AuthorizedAlways
    */
    func startMonitoring(region:CLBeaconRegion) {
        self.region = region
        let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:0]
        btManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
        setupLocalizationAuthorization()
    }

    ...

    // MARK - Bluetooth
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        beaconDelegate?.beaconManager(self, bluetoothConnectionStatus: peripheral.state)
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is in line 24. Just joking. Please show the code that isn't working

Comment: @Paulw11 I hope that will do :)

Comment: Is the code in your demo app (the one that is working) **identical** to what you posted here?

Comment: Have you tried turning your phone off/on?  Deleting the app from the device?

Comment:  i just realized that I made the most stupid mistake and post it. I forgot that in objc 'break' is required in the end of 'case' if you don't want to go to another 'case'. Of course now it's working.