# Blocking user when he doesn't agree to bluetooth or location services

Tags: ios, bluetooth, location

We’ve got an app that requires push notifications, bluetooth and usage of location services acceptance from the user in order to work properly. It’s essential for us, because without Bluetooth enabled user can’t connect to our tracking devices. We know, that we can’t block user on the screen when he doesn’t agree to push notifications, because that’s what App Store Review Guidelines states. The question is: can we block user on the screen until he turns on location and bluetooth?

Comment: `block user on the screen until he turns on location and bluetooth` sounds like a threat

Comment: I meant show him screen that says something like "turn on bluetooth" without a chance to go further

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your logic based on your requirements.

However you can check for different conditions for specific services enabled or not.

For Push Notifications:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```

For Location services:

```
 if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
// your code...
}
```

For Bluetooth:

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955007/how-to-get-the-status-of-bluetooth-on-off-in-iphone-programatically)

Comment: I know how to check those things, but I asked if my app will be rejected if I don't give access to the content of the app to the user who doesn't agree to location service usage or bluetooth

Comment: In that case, if such things are necessary then you can restrict application features, i.e If you disable the location services, then `Tinder` won't allow you to use the application.