# Objective C - CBCentralManager NSInternalInconsistencyException when leaving ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I was followed the code of [How to get the status of bluetooth (ON/OFF) in iphone programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955007/how-to-get-the-status-of-bluetooth-on-off-in-iphone-programatically) to get the status of bluetooth.

But when I pop the viewController by back navigation button, the app crashed with following error.

```
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x170261c80 of class CBCentralManager was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (  Context: 0x1aa9c3710, Property: 0x170056b90>  Context: 0x1aa9c3710, Property: 0x170056b00>  Context: 0x1aa9c3710, Property: 0x170056b90>  Context: 0x1aa9c3710, Property: 0x170056b00> )'

I was tried to remove the observers stated above when calling viewWillDisappear, but error still comes.

```
[self.bluetoothManager removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"state"];
[self.bluetoothManager removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];
```

And I tried

```
self.bluetoothManager.delegate = nil;
```

And

```
self.bluetoothManager = nil;
```

Sadly all of them no works.

Please give helps.

**Update:**

I want to show the system pop alert while bluetooth is not turned ON when calling - (void)detectBluetooth. So I add

```
[self.bluetoothManager init];
```

in - (void)detectBluetooth.

I found that make the error.

But I can't figure out another method to show the default popup(which with SETTING button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root reason why this error happening.

I did multiple init to the bluetooth manager, so it assign multiple observer itself.

Base on my purpose, to show system alert popup while bluetooth is not turn on. As `init` will pop the alert, I need to first set `nil` to bluetooth manager and `init` in later. That's works with no error.

Here is my final code:

```
if(!self.bluetoothManager)
{
    // Put on main queue so we can call UIAlertView from delegate callbacks.
    self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
} else{
    if (self.bluetoothManager.state != CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        self.bluetoothManager = nil;
        self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    }
}
[self centralManagerDidUpdateState:self.bluetoothManager];


- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch(self.bluetoothManager.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: [self pushViewController]; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestions: You could use a Singleton object for it (with potentially a delegate/notification) to make your push, or simply use a lazy init: `-(CBCentralManager)bluetoothManager{if(!self.bluuetoothManager){_bluetoothManager = alloc/init/settings, etc.} return _bluetoothManager;}` and in you code, always call your central manager with `self.bluetoothManager`

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!!