# iOS crash Assertion Failure on CBPeripheralManager AddService:

Tags: ios, crash, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing crash issue on iOS CoreBluetooth's
 `[CBPeripheralManager AddService:]`.

Seems it occurred due to assertion failure in `addService` method. Tried so many ways, still can't figure out the issue.

As per my understanding this is not null pointer exception as I already tested passing nil value as AddService parameter which yield different issue.

I have implemented all the delegates of CBPeripheralManager including CBCentral delegates.

In general it works fine. Normally I can't reproduce this issue with intention. But it occurs suddenly.

Please help
.
Crash log:

```
0   CoreFoundation                 0x18b3cafe0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x189e2c538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                 0x18b3caeb4 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
3   Foundation                     0x18be62720 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
4   CoreBluetooth                  0x1922ab420 -[CBPeripheralManager addService:] + 820
5   MyApp                        0x10110e1f4 -[MyPeripheralManager addServiceIntoPeripheralManager] (MyPeripheralManager.m:202)
```

Code Snipet:

```
-(void)addService{
if (!isServiceAdded) {
    CLLog("Add Service timer started");
    [backgroundTaskManager manageBackgroundRunningTask];
    /*
     AddService will be called after 5 seconds
     when application launching finished or iOS BT on
     */
    [self performSelector:@selector(addServiceIntoPeripheralManager) withObject:self afterDelay:SERVICE_ADDING_DELAY]; // 5 secs

} else {
    CLDbg("Service already added");
}
}
- (void)addServiceIntoPeripheralManager{
CLLog("Add Service timer expired");
CLDbg("Service Adding: %@", [UUIDString]);
[cbPeripheralManager addService:Service];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share some code which you try

Comment: please share your  code

Comment: code snippet is added,  would you please share the reason behind this type of assertion failure.

Comment: What is the text of the assertion failure?  This will describe what went wrong. Using timers to delay operations is a code smell. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Paulw11, I already added the crash log. It says, only Assertion failure. 
Delay is added to reduce frequent addService call when user kill app frequently after turned on.

Comment: There will be a text description that was passed to the assertion failure; you need to find this in your console log or you are just guessing.  You should only add the service in response to a poweredOn state (or poweredOn state plus subsequent user action). It should not be possible for your app to attempt to add the service more than once

Comment: @Paulw11, 
given AddService() is called from another file's addService() where I checked BT status before calling addService(). Like below:

`__ another file __

- (void)addService{
    if( serviceUUID && bleManagerState.peripheralPowerState == BLE_MANAGER_STATE_POWER_ON
       && (bleManagerState.serviceState != BLE_MANAGER_STATE_SERVICE_ADDED
           || bleManagerState.serviceState != BLE_MANAGER_STATE_SERVICE_ADDING) ) {
           bleManagerState.serviceState = BLE_MANAGER_STATE_SERVICE_ADDING;
           [peripheralManager addService];
       }
}
`

Comment: But what calls that addservice?  Checking state variables like that is asking for timing related race condition issues; in particular there should be no "adding" state. Either you have added the service or you haven't. In `didDetermineState` just add the service when you get the `poweredOn` state.

Comment: yes, there is no adding step, I added this step to maintain internal state and for debugging. 
Actually this is a sometimes issue. In general case, I didn't find that issue. Everything works fine. 
But testers reporting this crash issue where they don't have console level access.

Answer (score 1):

You are not implementing the callback updates of your BluetoothManager

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558191/4466607)

and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31449624/4466607)

I hope this will help you

Comment: I have implemented all the delegates of CBPeripheralManager including CBCentral delegates. In general it works fine. Normally I can't reproduce this issue with intention. But it occurs suddenly.